# The real world location of Akiba Dome

Tags: tourism, love-live

Where is the Akiba Dome that is mentioned in  Love Live! School Idol the Movie? At first since it says Akiba, I thought it would be in Akiba, Japan. But then, considering Ootonokizaka High's location (near Akiba), it doesn't make sense that they would go there on plane. Later on the Statue of Liberty was shown, so the Akiba Dome should be somewhere in New York, right? But where exactly in New York is that, because when I Googled, there is no such a thing such as Akiba Dome.

If it is actually a fictional place, what real world place is it modeled after? I guess the Madison Square Garden, just a guess though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after re-watching it, at 6:28 of the movie,

> Umi: Why are we going overseas in the first place? If it's a concert, can't we just do it in Japan?
>  Kotori: Remember what my mom said? A TV station over here wanted to do a report on school idols, so they gave Otonizaka High the offer.

So basically, they are in US for the TV station's offer and not for the third Love Live.

As for the location of Tokyo Dome, this [site](http://lovelive-matome.com/archives/akibadome0709.html) suggests that Akiba Dome is actually a reference to Tokyo Dome. The title in the site says

【劇場版ラブライブ】秋葉ドームはやっぱ東京ドームじゃね！？こことかモロじゃん！【僕光】(21:00)

The first sentence if translated into English means

[Love Live the Movie] Akiba Dome is Tokyo Dome, right?

Considering that the site is in Japanese (high probability of owned and maintained by Japanese community), and that they suggest that Akiba Dome is Tokyo Dome means that Akiba Dome doesn't actually exists in the real world.

Comment: IMHO, the director didn't do a great job with it as at the first part of the movie they are talking about the Third Love Live taking place at Akiba Dome and then suddenly having the girls go to other country without even explaining where they are going, thus causing the whole confusion.